# Change default xorg.conf video driver

Tags: debian, xorg, video, lightdm

Debian 11 here with LXDE (Xorg + lightdm)

How could I change the driver used by X?

My X is using the default options, I have no **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** file, so I generate one with the command `sudo X -configure :1` and after that copying the contents of **/root/xorg.conf.new** to **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

After reboot I have a running X on :0 like before (`ps auxww | grep Xorg` returns *... /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -s 0 :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch*), but with a blank screen (no EE in **/var/log/Xorg.0.log** file). If I remove that **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** file and reboot I have a normal screen again.

The generated **/root/xorg.conf.new** is this (removed commented options, some FontPaths and SubSections Display's, for brevity)

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"

    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Noticed that without an **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** file the output names returned by `xrandr` have a dash, like DP-1, DP-2 etc and with that file `xrandr` return those names without a dash: DP1, DP2...

The only change I want to do is replace:

> Driver      "intel"

with

> Driver      "fbdev"

Already tried to remove the xserver-xorg-video-intel package but it would break my system removing the WM, DE and a lot of other apps.

Comment: Are you running a standard Debian kernel or a customized one? If you run `cat /proc/fb`, what does it say? Have you installed the `xserver-xorg-video-fbdev` package? Without that package, setting `Driver "fbdev"` will not work, and the X server will then automatically try and find other drivers that might work. Instead of creating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, you might try taking just the `Section "Device"... EndSection` part from `/root/xorg.conf.new` and place just that part into e.g. `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/device.conf`, letting the X server auto-detect the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @telcoM: Standard kernel, `cat /proc/fb` returns: **0 radeondrmfb**, `xserver-xorg-video-fbdev` package is installed, tried to place just the `Section "Device"` part in a file inside **/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d** but without success, tried to specify a custom **xorg.conf**, with the `xserver-config` parameter of **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** file, set but the same blank screen happen too.
Even with the original **xorg.conf.new** generated, without any changes, placed in **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** I have a blank screen.

Comment: Sorry @telcoM, as I explained in the edit and in the answer, I mixed machines while researching this, so, to correct my answer in your first question the output of `cat /proc/fb` is: **0 i915drmfb** the other ones are the same: packages installed and configuration files placed in different directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little confusion by my side, so I have to make the appropriate corrections to get in, I think, a somewhat good explanation.

I'm working on several machines trying to make that driver change, and I mixed the results with the machine with **radeon** driver and the machine with the **intel** driver, my bad.

The problem is that the intel driver (**xserver-xorg-video-intel**, not radeon, fixed already) does not generate output names with the dash (DP1), when using the **/etc/X11/xorg.conf** file, but without that file those names are generated with the dashes (DP-1) and since my screens are configured using a set of xrandr scripts, generated when I was using an Xorg without a **/etc/X11/xorg.conf file**, that script could not set my screens.